# Point domain to subdomain of another domain

Tags: php, dns, cpanel, whm

I've been having troubles solving this issue for a couple of days now. Let me explain what's going on.

The users of my website get a wildcard domain name to use. They can create a simple website using that subdomain name.

Recently, I've started offering them to purchase a domain name through the website. The idea was that the domain name they purchase should show the same website as the wildcard domain.

I've figured that I could achieve that by pointing the domain name to that subdomain name. But, I am not sure whether or not that is possible and how I can achieve it. Btw, I have access to both cPanel and WHM, so I can freely edit the DNS zones and create accounts if required.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not the best at this, but I would think you would have to create a vhost for every domain that has been registered and point it to the proper directory.

If you want to do it with DNS I suppose you have to set a CNAME for *.domain.tld to the proper subdomain. But I don't know if that would at some point redirect them to their original subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

just follow these steps.

- add a cname record in main.com dns mapping to the subdomain you like
- eg. example.com.        CNAME  example.maincom.

Done